# Two routes for the same resource in Rails (for SEO purposes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is a possible id of a post:

```
tj1nbomj3m
```

Now, lets say that we want to go to that post's page. Well, we would do:

```
/posts/tj1nbomj3m
```

BUT we are also SEO minded. Although doing `posts/:id` will work, I'm a little concerned for SEO. Therefore, I'd rather do `posts/:id/:title` with a redirect from `posts/:id` to `posts/:id/:title`.

I know how to do this in Laravel, but I have no idea how one would do it in Rails. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **routes.rb**

```
resources :posts
get '/posts/:id/:title' => 'posts#show', as: 'post_by_title'
```

Now in your controller

```
def show
  @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
  if !params[:title]
    redirect_to video_by_title_path(@post.id, @post.title)
  end
end
```

Finally, to build the URLs

```
post_path(@post)
#=> "/posts/post_id"

post_by_title_path(@post.id, @post.title)
#=> "/posts/post_id/post-title"
```